# How do I save GridSearchCV, RandomizedSearchSV permanently in google-colab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory, joblib

So I want to save my GridSearchCV results permanently in google-colab.

I was using

`joblib.dump(rnd_search.best_estimator_,"rnd_search_best.pkl"`

and it saved it in the files tab under content, but it always gets erased, when I restart the notebook. Is there a way to save it permanently like the notebook on my google drive, so i can access it everytime and don't have to go through the long process again.